# How to CreatMap List of Object with appling conditions Automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net, automapper

I have Domain object ProductType. It contains parentproducttypeId column. If product type is a subset of another producttype that parentproducttypeId to set to that producttypeId.(ex: T-Shirt is a subset of Casual wears)

```
public class ProductType : IEntityBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int PerentProductTypeId { get; set; }
    public int Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedOnUTC { get; set; }
}
```

In API view model I have two classes

```
public class ParentProductTypeModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ChildProductTypeModel> ChildProductTypeList { get; set; }

    public ParentProductTypeModel()
    {
        ChildProductTypeList = new List<ChildProductTypeModel>();
    }
}

public class ChildProductTypeModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I need to Map returned List of Product Type to this ParentProductTypeModel List with setting all subset lists according to there parentproducttypeId. If parentproducttypeId equals to 0 it is parentproduct.

Comment: So there is only one level of parents and one level of children?

Comment: I don't get your comment. By the way I don't know the way I going to createMapping is wrong ? At the end I just need parent model with list of children . In the domain class all parents and children in samedata set and parent producttype does not contain parentproducttypeId and child producttype contains relevant parentproducttypeId.

Comment: Show an example of before and after.

Comment: I have done this using another column in view model as same as did in the domain level.

Comment: Post an answer or delete your question.